# How can I monitor the energy impact of peripheral devices connected to my Macbook?

Tags: macos, battery, power-management, apple-silicon, energy

How can I monitor the energy impact of peripheral devices connected to my Macbook? I want to see if my external HDD is draining my battery or not.

Comment: Is the drive thunderbolt or USB for the power / data request (I'm assuming it's not powered by wall power, but many drives are that, too.) Is there a reason why the battery gauge built into macOS isn't working for your needs?

Comment: @bmike USB 2 HDD, pretty old. Not using wall power. What builtin battery gauge? That only shows which apps are using significant energy, not which peripherals. I want a quantitative measure, preferably in watts currently drawed by the device.

Comment: Are you sure it's USB2? That is limited to 2.5W. And it would be very old. I'd be more worried about it failing than its power use.

Answer (score 3):

If the external HDD is connected solely through USB (bus powered) it is most certainly drawing current. If the HD inside is constantly spinning, the drive is pulling a constant current. If you set "Put hard disks to sleep when possible" in the Energy Save System preference, and the disk is actually spun down, only the current needed to maintain the external drive's electronics are drawing from your laptop.

A typical external HDD draws 4 watts of energy. This 4 watt figure is from [LaCie Support](https://www.lacie.com/support/kb/mobile-devices-and-power-requirements-006329en/). Text below extracted from this page.

*"Mobile drives are commonly referred to as "Bus-Powered" devices. They don't typically require an external power supply, and are powered by the ports on a computer. Most mobile drives require approximately 4 watts of energy to run. Most computers produce this, so it isn't usually a problem.*

***Multiple Drives***

*It is possible to run multiple bus powered drives, but note the amount of power taken. Two drives takes the power requirement to 8 watts, which few computers can do comfortably. Also, a laptop will quickly have its battery drained, and that can cause an interruption in communication with the hard disk (which can translate to data loss)"*

- Edited to add:
  This [USB power meter device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FMQZVW2) can be used to measure voltage from 3.7V-30V, and measure current from: 0-4A.

Comment: Is there any way to actually see how many watts the device is drawing in real time?

Comment: See my edit above which answers your comment. You can use this [volt to watt](https://www.rapidtables.com/calc/electric/Volt_to_Watt_Calculator.html)  calculator too!